# I wanted to add ItemListener for jList but i m unable to do so ,suggest me how can i add itemListener for listbox

Tags: java, swing

further, when I add  Item listener for combo box it allows me to do so...

```
 jComboBox1.addItemListener(this);  
    jList1.addItemListener(this);
```

here is what i have defined in the itemStateChanged method.

```
 public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
   if(e.getSource()==jComboBox1)
   {
        jLabel1.setText("Selected Item="+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"   "+"selected Index="+jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex());
   }
   if(e.getSource()==jList1)
   {
       jLabel2.setText("Selected items= "+jList1.getSelectedValue());
   }
```

Comment: "*I wanted to add ItemListener for jList but i m unable to do so*" - Why? Is there an error or an exception? If so, please post the error message / stack trace. If not, why can't you do so? --- Does the code you showed work? --- `if(e.getSource()==jComboBox1)` are you sure you can use `==` here? ---

Comment: @Turing85: why not? It should be a reference to the actual combo box passed from `getSource()`. The OP *should* post a valid [mcve] so we can tell what they're doing wrong without guessing.

Comment: Don't use an ItemListener but rather a ListSelectionListener. Please check the [JList Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for the details.

Comment: thnx a lot  Hovercraft Full Of Eels!!